# Server to Server communication in microservices

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

I am working on microservice architecture, but I am facing some challenges in that.

First let me give you a brief about the architecture.

1. User logs in and get a signed token which will be used to call all REST APIS.
2. There will be lot of API server where APIs are secured using Spring security and Authorized as per the user roles.
3. Services have to interact with each other to get/update information.
4. Every service will have the power to validate a token issue by auth server.

Problem:-

1. Everything works fine if User logs in and the same token is used and passsed to every service which is validated across.So, services dont need to trust each other as the token is passed.
2. Now, the problem is there are some services which needs to be called from server itself without logging in. Lets say a server to server call. How will a service authenticate and authorize the call from other services.

I read about spring Microservices but Zuul is also not the saviour here as every API server has spring security embedded and not just the API gateway.

One solution can be that every service has its own default user with certaing roles which is used to Login->Fetch a token->call other server api with token.

Can you please give me some pointers in server to server calls where each server is authenticated and authorized using spring security.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't secure those services, or allow access to everyone from a certain IP address. Just write the correct security rules.

Comment: @M.Deinum... these services need to be secured as they will be called from external clients as well like mobiles/REST.

Comment: As I mentioned just write the proper security rules, if internal (or specific IP range) allow access, else a token is needed. So it all comes down to proper security rules, instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: @M.Deinum so are you saying to write a rule like if Ip is localhost then just dont authenticate and authorize everything?

Comment: @M.Deinum ohh yeas..i forgot this point in spring security. Looks correct let me try this one. Thanks!!!

Comment: @M.Deinum I found that I can use IP for this..but now if I am using a proxy then it will be always localIP, in that case I can use X-forwarded-for, so can you tellme how good and bullet proof is to use X-Forwarded-For to check for localhost. If someone has included tht header in the request than those request will be authenticated, so only if X-forwarded-For contain localhost then it will not be authenticated. Wht u say?

Comment: I would recommend not allowing microservices to use synchronous communication at all (between microservices, ok for UI/Client to use an api) (use messaging and pub/sub instead).

Comment: @SeanFarmar I agree with you, we need to go with Async way. But that will require a lot of change and due to other constraints I cant go with that, so need to do REST only between services.

Comment: RaghavTandon,  @M.Deinum I have the same scenario. Can you please guide me how can I implement the IP rule?

Comment: @mav3n Can you trust your services internally? If yes, then no need to add any security filters else you need to pass some sort of token generated to downstream service which will again be authenticated and forms the Auth principal.

Comment: @RaghavTandon Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am doing the same, passing the auth token to downstream service. Figured out that IP whitelisting won't be a solution to this as UI will also be on the same IP and I don't want it to bypass auth for UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OAuth2, there is a flow dedicated to server-to-server authorization (Client Credentials Grant Flow). The calling service is a regular client for the second (the resource server), so it must get a token and use it.

In a nutshell, the client tells the authorization server who is he (using its client id / app id), the authorization server gives it a token, which can be used to query the resource server.

I have a resource in french [here](http://www.bubblecode.net/fr/2016/01/22/comprendre-oauth2/#Lrsquoautorisation_serveur_serveur_Client_Credentials_Grant), the sequence diagram is in english and should be helpful. You can find more information about this flow easily.

For the Spring Security specific stuff, see the [spring-security-oauth2 doc](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

Comment: right now i am not using OAuth. But I think the above comments where i can bypass security for IP address can be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, in the Microservices architecture we should not call the other services within a service. We should instead use the **Publisher/Subscriber** approach for server to server communication.

Even though if you wish to do it, just **pass the Auth-Token as a Header used for authenticating the service to the downstream service**, where the token will again be authenticated and thus will give response once authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approuch:

- [Key Authentication Security Patterns In Microservice Architecture](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/key-authentication-security-patterns-in-microservice-architecture/)
- [Authentication between microservices: Is it really that hard?](https://www.doit.com/authentication-between-microservices-is-it-really-that-hard/)

The more security You need, the more complicated solution.
Form direct authentication with the trusted subsystem to Publisher/Subscriber approach or Mutual TLS (mTLS).