# Quick solution to handle service to service authentication in a microservices architecture

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, amazon-cognito

I’m new to microservices and authentication and I’m trying to understand how to implement authentication in a microservices architecture with the least development effort possible.

From what I’ve understood, there are two possible authentication scenarios in a microservices architecture:

1) A user wants to access one of the microservices

2) One of the microservices wants to access another microservice

I’ve understood how a user can access one of the microservices via a JWT, and it seems to me that the quickest way to implement this is using an IdaaS offering such as AWS Cognito or Google Cloud Identity Platform.

I’m struggling to understand how can I solve the microservice to microservice authentication part though.

Let’s say that a user access microservice A via a JWT. At this point, microservice A needs to access microservice B. And then microservice B needs to access microservice C. 
How should the authentication between services A, B and C be handled? What’s the quickest way to implement this? Can I use something like AWS Cognito again? How?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Have you considered having all microservices in a private network, so there's no need for authentication between microservices and exposing an API gateway which takes care of authentication for your clients?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant. This flow is used for service to service authentication. Each service will use its own credentials to acquire a token from the token service and use that to call another service.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approuch:

- [Key Authentication Security Patterns In Microservice Architecture](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/key-authentication-security-patterns-in-microservice-architecture/)
- [Authentication between microservices: Is it really that hard?](https://www.doit.com/authentication-between-microservices-is-it-really-that-hard/)
- [Server to Server communication in microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854185/server-to-server-communication-in-microservices)

The more security You need, the more complicated solution:
from direct authentication with the trusted subsystem to Publisher/Subscriber approach or Mutual TLS (mTLS).

Answer (score 0):

Some service mesh solutions provide service-to-service auth through **mTLS** e.g. Istio.

Another approach will be to have another JWT for your services. Service A will issue its own JWT and sends it to service B. Service B makes sure that the claims are valid (e.g. the `iss` represents service A, and `aud` represents service B, the token has not been replayed, etc.). If all is good, service B issues its own token and sends it to service C which will also validate the token.

IMPORTANT:

RFC [Proof of Posession Key for JWTs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800)

I personally prefer Proof of Possession with an Asymmetric Key: the JWT must be signed by a private key that the issuer only knows. So it should be kept as a secret. The public key should be shared to the other services so that they can verify the JWT signature.

How I implemented it:
The presenter (service that sends the request) is also the issuer (issues the JWT). The key (e.g. Google application credentials) that is used to sign the JWT is downloaded from my cloud provider. The cloud provider acts as the key manager and has a JWKs endpoint, where the the issuer's public key can be fetched and looked up by a key ID.
The recipient (service that receives and validates the request), will fetch the public from the cloud provider (key manager) and will verify the JWT.

Note: you have to understand and take advantage of the JWT claims to enforce security.

Note 2: key management is probably complicated depending on the situation. You need to have a key rotation policy to make things more secure.